# Taking integers as input from console and storing them in an array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

When I am trying to write the following code, the computer takes several inputs. But what I want is it should take only one line as an input and save all the integers in that line in an array. Can you help me with this please?

```
import java.util.*;

class InputInteger{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array=new int[20];
        int i=0;
        while(input.hasNext()){
          array[i]=input.nextInt();
          i++;
        }     
        input.close();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> But what I want is it should take only one line as an input and save all the integers in that line in an array.

First, I urge you not to `close()` a `Scanner` that you have created around `System.in`. That's a global, and `close()`ing can cause you all kinds of issues later (because you can't reopen it). As for reading a single line of input and splitting `int` values into an array, you could do use [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) and something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
        int[] vals = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            vals[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
    }
}
```

**Edit** Based on your comment,

```
String line = "1 31 41 51";
String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
int[] vals = new int[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    vals[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```

Output is

```
[1, 31, 41, 51]
```

If you need to handle errors, I suggest you use a `List` like

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    try {
        al.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
}
// You could now print the List
System.out.println(al);
// And if you must have an `int[]` copy it like.
int[] vals = new int[al.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    vals[i] = al.get(i);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this prints an error when I input numbers like 1 31 41 51 etc. How can that be dealt with?

Comment: Edited based on your comment. What is etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the input as `String` and use `for` loop to process it:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
int[] array=new int[20];
String numbers = input.nextLine();
for(int i = 0 ; i<numbers.length() ; i++){
    array[i]=Character.getNumericValue(numbers.charAt(i));
}
```

But in this case, the number of digits must be not exceed your array size, which is 20. Or else it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` Exception. You may want to do Exception handling on this.

Or to avoid that, you can declare your array with size equal to length of the input:

```
int[] array=new int[numbers.length()];
```

[See the demo here](http://ideone.com/q0TU2x)

Comment: Thanks. But what if my input is like this: 1 21 31 41 51 and so on.  In this case how will I make an array of integers 1, 21, 31, 41 etc?

Comment: @PrabhjotRai ah good question! For that case, you should refer to [@Elliott Frisch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27241147/3152527) answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    boolean repeat = true;
    while (repeat) {
        System.out
                .print("Enter a bunch of integers seperated by spaces, or 'q' to quit: ");
        String line = input.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("q"))
            repeat = false;
        else {
            String[] numbers = line.split("\\s+");
            for (String num : numbers) {
                if (!nums.contains(num))
                    nums.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
            }
        }
    }
    for (Integer i : nums) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    input.close();
```